# How to compare input from a user php post to a MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am teaching myself php and MySQL, and right now I have a problem with MySQL.

I want to compare the phone number that the user put in with the phone number in MYSQL, and if it is in MYSQL to not register it again.

My code:

```
<?php

require_once 'connection/connection.php';

// Variables from HTML to php
$worker_Name = $_POST['workerNameFromHtml']; // worker Name
$worker_City = $_POST['workerCityFromHtml']; // workerCity
$worker_career = $_POST['workerCareerFromHtml']; // worker career
$worker_PhoneNumber = $_POST['workerPhonNumberFromHtml']; // worker Phone Number
$worker_SecondPhoneNumber = $_POST['workerSecondPhoneNumberFromHtml']; // worker Second Phone Number
$submt=$_POST['submitFromHtml'];

if($submt){

  $qry = ( "SELECT workrPhoneNumber FROM workersTable WHERE workrPhoneNumber = '$worker_PhoneNumber'") or die(mysql_error()); 
  $result = $connect->query($qry);
  $num = $result->num_rows;

  if ($num == 1) {
    $here = "INSERT INTO workersTable VALUES('','$worker_Name','$worker_City','$worker_career','$worker_PhoneNumber','$worker_SecondPhoneNumber')";
    $query = $connect->query($here);
    print "Successfully added!";
  }
  else {print "This number has already been entered Thank you for your cooperation!";}}

$connect->close();
```

So far I have not found a solution to this problem.

Comment: your `$qry` variable is wrong. check this tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: i was changed the wrong. but not working.
i'll change and edit my question to my final file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your biggest problem here is that you are trying to include variables inside of a string.

```
"SELECT workrPhoneNumber FROM workersTable WHERE workrPhoneNumber = '$worker_PhoneNumber'"
```

If you want to do it this way, you need to concatenate your variables with your string.

```
"SELECT workrPhoneNumber FROM workersTable WHERE workrPhoneNumber = '".$worker_PhoneNumber."'"
```

Keep in mind if you do this you will want to sanitize your variables first to prevent SQL injections.  Also, when you INSERT variables, you will actually want to use a prepared statement like this:

```
"INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...) VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)"
```

where the 1st set of values are the names of your columns in the database and the second set are your PHP variables you are putting into it.